# How does "Attach to Process" work if the source code is in other folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I have a web application developed at `d:\projects\webapplication1` and it is published at `d:\websites\webapplication1`. I am browsing the website in IIS and attaching the process in visual studio, and it works. So, how does the debugger work in this case despite the source code and published code are in different locations.

Comment: I think you are debugging your "production". Depends where IIS is pointing to...

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee452b7d-46e3-46c4-8266-e2b3633eff7b/setting-source-code-location-in-pdb-files?forum=clr  ... And http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know for general info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDB files contain the absolute paths of the source files used to build the binaries. The sources will be automatically found if the absolute paths are valid.

Comment: They probably have been shadow-copied already. Search entire drive C: for *.pdb and delete everything suspicious. Restart Visual Studio. Who knows what caches there are.

Answer (score 1):

The published code probably has a PDB file which has the file path for your code.  The code will contain some debugging information (used for stack traces for instance) even without the PDB file being generated.